# Rails, CanCan and controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have an `Employee` model in my application. An Employee *belongs to a company*, and a Company *has many employees*. Now i have two controllers for the employees; a normal `employees_controller` and a namespaced controller for the companies to manage employees under `/company/employees_controller`. This is because employees should be able to edit their accounts, but so should companies. The information they are able to edit is fairly different though, and so a company would edit an employee thru the `company/employees_controller` and an employee would edit their profile thru the `employees_controller`. Is there a way to specfy a controller in *CanCan*? In my abilities for companies i have  `can :manage, Employee,  :company_id => user.id if user.status? :confirmed`. But i only wan't a company to be able to manage an Employee thru the namespaced controller at `company/employee_controller`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should probably have done some better research before asking: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorization-for-Namespaced-Controllers